# Custom Checkout page

Tags: theming, forms

I have made a form_alter in template.php in my theme and I have created a custom page (page--checkout.tpl.php) to render my form.
If I render the content as print render($page['content']); everything is fine,
but I want to print the cart content on the top of the page, and the customer_profile_billing and commerce_payment below the cart contents in two seaprate columns. How can i call for these seperate panes in the page--checkout.tpl.php in order to show them the way I need?

I've searched everywhere but it seems that I cannot find something that works for my needs.

Thank you in advance everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it might seem a little noobish mistake but nevertheless, for everyone that is interested out there.

After a lot of research I found out how to make it.

The problem that arises when you try to render a form in a .tpl file is the functionality of the form.

I was trying to render `$page['content']`
and I couldn't do the above.

So I had to add to `MYTHEME\template.php` these lines:

```
function MYTHEME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'commerce_checkout_form_checkout' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'commerce-checkout-form-checkout',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/template/forms',
    ),
  );
}
```

and then I created: `commerce-checkout-form-checkout.tpl.php` in
MYTHEME/template/forms

and I just put this code inside:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12"><?php print render($form['cart_contents']); ?></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6"><?php print render($form['customer_profile_billing']); ?></div>
  <div class="col-sm-6"><?php print render($form['commerce_payment']); ?></div>
</div>
<?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?>
```

The key to render the form right was the last line:

```
<?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?>
```

which rendered all the missing funcionality (like ajax and submit buttons) from the form.

I hope this will help someone in the future to avoid all the time and hassle..